# Declaring a variable in PHP and issue with @ error suppression

Tags: php, variables, mpdf

what does the following codeline do?

```
$this->wordData[$wordCount] = ((@$this->wordData[$wordCount] << $remainingBit) | ($bufferVal >> $bufferBit));
```

It's a snippet of qrcode of mpdf (line 444). since PHP 8 it throws **PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 43** for example.
I know @ is PHP error-suppression, but since PHP 8 it is working another way as it does before PHP 8.
The part after the "=" --> ((variable << variable) | variable) is that a kind of if than (with | for OR)? I'm confused ;-)

I am teaching myself PHP and would therefore be glad if someone could help me with an explanation for beginners.

Thanks

Andreas

Comment: @waterloomatt You're right, my bad

Answer (score -2):

There have been some changes in error suppression in PHP8 - see https://php.watch/versions/8.0/fatal-error-suppression

Note that the `<<` and `>>` are bitwise operators to shift the bits of a number left or right, respectively.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php